UBLOX RTK GPS in ROS Noetic
I am using the ublox F9P GPS for my autonomous navigation. For having the precise location, I am using the ublox_gps and ntrip_ros package by using the following guideline "https://velog.io/@swooeun/ROS-Ublox-ZED-F9P-RTK-UTM". The packages are built successfully, but I am still not receiving the RTK-Fix signal. Also the ntrip is connected successfully but their is no rtcm messages coming on topic.
Below is the summary of ntrip_ros launch file:
roslaunch ntrip_ros ntrip_ros.launch
... logging to /home/darlab/.ros/log/487ce4f4-bea7-11ef-b497-b7ce74edade4/roslaunch-darlab-50194.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://darlab:35971/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /ntrip_ros/nmea_gga: $GPGGA,045028.146...
 * /ntrip_ros/ntrip_pass: ngii
 * /ntrip_ros/ntrip_server: RTS2.ngii.go.kr:2101
 * /ntrip_ros/ntrip_stream: FKP-RTCM31
 * /ntrip_ros/ntrip_user: imranturi5
 * /ntrip_ros/rtcm_topic: /ublox_gps/rtcm
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.17.0

NODES
  /
ntrip_ros (ntrip_ros/ntripclient.py)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[ntrip_ros-1]: started with pid [50215]
send: b'GET /FKP-RTCM31 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: RTS2.ngii.go.kr:2101\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nContent-Length: 66\r\nNtrip-Version: Ntrip/2.0\r\nUser-Agent: NTRIP ntrip_ros\r\nConnection: close\r\nAuthorization: Basic aW1yYW50dXJpNTpuZ2lp\r\n\r\n'
send: b'$GPGGA,045028.146,3752.106,N,12744.626,E,1,12,1.0,0.0,M,0.0,M,,*64'
reply: 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n'


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
